# How to set array length after updating it via $addToSet in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Document structure looks like this,

```
{
    blacklists:[]         // elements should be unique
    blacklistsLength:0    // length of blacklists
}
```

Adding sets of value to `blacklists` is easy.

```
db.posts.update({_id:...}, {$addtoSet:{blacklists:{$each:['peter', 'bob', 'steven']}}});
```

But How can I update `blacklistLength` at the same time to reflect the changes?

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible. Either you have

1. Update the length seperately using a subsequent findAndModify
   command or
2. You can do it per name and rewrite the query using a negation in
   your criteria and $push rather than $addToSet (not necessarily
   needed but a lot faster with large blacklists since addToSet is
   always o(n) regardless of indexes) :

   ```
   db.posts.update({_id:..., blacklists:{$ne:'peter'}}, {$push:{blacklists:{'peter'}},$inc:{blacklistsLength: 1}});
   ```

The latter being perfectly safe since the list and the length are adjusted atomically but obviously has slightly degraded performance. Since it also has the benefit of better overall performance due to the $push versus $addToSet performance issue on large arrays (and blacklists tend to become huge and remember that the $push version of the update uses an index on blacklist in the update criteria while $addToSet will NOT use an index during it's set scan) it is generally the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Would the following not work?

```
db.posts.update({_id:...}, {
  $addtoSet:{blacklists:{$each:['peter', 'bob', 'steven']}},
  $set: {blacklistsLength: ['peter', 'bob', 'steven'].length}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, please see the discussion here: [google groups mongo](https://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/cf5bdd261f8fb49/98c2cceba6361d38)

As you can notice, following to this discussion, a bug was open:
[Mongo Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3409)

Answer (score 0):

As you upsert items into the database, simply query the item to see if it's in your embedded array. That way, you're avoiding pushing duplicate items, and only incrementing the counter as you add new items.

```
q = {'blacklists': {'$nin': ['blacklist_to_insert'] }}
u = {
 '$push' : {'blacklists': { 'blacklist_to_insert' } },
 '$inc' : {'total_blacklists': 1 }
}
o = { 'upsert' : true }

db.posts.update(q,u,o)
```